# splitting content by ID (1st column) and generate new data file based on format

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

How i want to split content to multiple files using date format as following below:

```
Test_<ID name><ddmmyyyy>.CSV
```

How can I split according to the format?

as before this i use:

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1 {print > "Test_<ID name><ddmmyyyy>.CSV_"$1".csv"}' Original.CSV
```

### Edit

I got there with

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Test_01012020.CSV
```

but then I want to include my column name too. How?

Comment: @j. chomel thanks but i want the file in format : Test_<Name><ddmmyyyy>.CSV

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove double quotes using awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338647/how-to-remove-double-quotes-using-awk)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [variables from the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) in your thing:

```
_DATE=` date '+%d%m%Y' `
_ID=my_value
F_EXT=${_ID}${_DATE}
# here "var" is set to the value defined from the shell "F_EXT"
awk -v var=${F_EXT} -F"," 'NR>1 {print > "Test_" var ".CSV_"$1".csv"}' Original.CSV
```

(I didn't get where you were taking your "ID name", so here it's `my_value`)

### Edit

If you want to include your column name, then read it with the case when `NR==1`:

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS="," } NR==1 {COLUMN_NAME=$1} NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"COLUMN_NAME"_"DATE".csv"}' a.txt
```

Comment: @J.chomel..actually i want to split file into multiple file then save the file in format example Test<Customer_Name><ddmmyyyy>.CSV..but then how can i create such as the format? I still cannot find it..i want to use awk technique..i already find out how to split but i could not find how to split in format?

Comment: @FARAH, its so very unclear... Could you update your original post (OP) with input format and expected output format? Is it CSV format, e.g. fields from original file separated with `,`? But if your input is already CSV, then you just add the line... Or do you want the header line repeated in each file?

Comment: I got already by using this command **awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Test_01012020.CSV** but then I want to include my column name too. How?  @J. Chomel