# Split file into multiple file using awk, but in date format

Tags: linux, awk, scripting

I want to split a file into multiple files and save the file in date format.

Why doesn't this command work?

```
awk -v DATE= date '+%d%m%Y'-F"," 'NR>1 { print > "Test_" DATE ".CSV_"$1".csv"}' Testing.CSV
```

Comment: This is a follow-up of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292805/splitting-content-by-id-1st-column-and-generate-new-data-file-based-on-format

Comment: Why not just use awk's own date functions.  I see no need to use the shell version instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```
awk -F, -v date=$(date +%d%m%Y) 'NR>1{print > "Test_"date".CSV_"$1".csv"}' file
```

if not, try first

```
awk -v date=$(date +%d%m%Y) 'BEGIN{print date}'
```

to check whether date is correctly set as an `awk` variable.

Comment: @RavinderSingh : This is my successfull command: awk -v DATE="$(date +"%Y%m%d")" -F"," 'NR>1 { print > "Assignment_"$1""DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV but it come out with this: Assignment_"A"_01012017 I want to remove "__", can you help me?

Comment: if you don't want the underscore char, remove it from the command.  The empty string "" before DATE is not necessary.  Also, all caps variable naming is not recommended since it can override `awk` defined variables unintentionally.

Comment: I just want to remove the double quoatation, as it "$1" then it will appear "A", I just want it appear only A without double quotation

Comment: I just want to remove the double quoatation, as it "$1" then it will appear "A", I just want it appear only A without double quotation

Comment: I think your field $1 has quote marks in the original input file, you can remove them with `gsub(/"/,"",$1)`

Comment: I cannot find it..I put the above command but it give me sub not A. I want **A** only without "____"

Answer (score 1):

@FARAH: Try:

```
awk -v DATE=$(date +%d%m%Y) -F"," 'NR>1 { print > "Test_" DATE ".CSV_"$1".csv"}'   Input_file
```

As there is lack of information about samples and expected output so seeing that your command needs to some fine tuned, try above and let us know if this helps.

Comment: Don't you mean `$(date +%d%m%Y)`? Currently, `DATE` is set to the literal string `date +%d%m%Y`.

Comment: awk -v DATE="$(date +"%Y%m%d")" -F"," 'NR>1 { print > "Test_" DATE ".CSV_"$1".csv"}' input_file  I try this..cannot also\

Comment: Thanks you Benjamin, I corrected it now, thank you for guiding here, I haven't tested the previous one actually.

Comment: @karakfa  ----- This is my successfull command:
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%Y%m%d")" -F"," 'NR>1 { print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV

but it come out with this:


Assignment_"A"_01012017


I want to remove "___", can you help me?