# How to remove double quotes using awk

Tags: linux, awk, scripting

This is my command:

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%Y%m%d")" -F"," 'NR>1 { print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV
```

but it come out with this:

```
Assignment_"A"_01012017
```

I want to remove "___", can you help me?

I find out this:

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV
```

but after I run this command, my file can be assignment_A_01012017 but then inside my file..the column not seperated into column. How?

Comment: I don't see any `"___"` in your output.

Comment: @pfnuesel yes. But actually I want to remove "____" if I do this command **awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'NR>1 { print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Test_01012020.CSV** my file naming will be like **Assignment_"A"_01012017 but actually I want **Assignment_A_01012017** without "__"

Comment: Then remove the `"`.

Comment: @pfnuesel I remove it but it come out with **Assigment_$1_01012017**

Comment: show some sample of your input and expected output so we can see where is your problem.

Comment: I already get it by using this command **awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV** but I want column name also inside my file. how? @NeronLeVelu

Answer (score 1):

Use below `awk`

```
awk -F, -v DATE="$(date +'%Y%m%d')" 'NR>1{s=$1; gsub(/"/,"",s);  print > "Assignment_"s"_"DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F, -v DATE="$(date +'%Y%m%d')" '    # Start awk, where field sep being  comma
                                         # and variable DATE with current date
     NR>1{                               # If no records greater than 1 then 
            s=$1;                        # save field1 data to variable s
            gsub(/"/,"",s);              # substitute double quote with null in variable s, so here we remove quote

            # print current record/line to file Assigment_{field1}_{current_date}.csv
            # {field1} = value of variable s after removing double quote
            # {current_date} = value of variable DATE

            print > "Assignment_"s"_"DATE".csv"
         }
     ' Text_01012020.CSV
```

Comment: thank you. I already get it. but then how can I put column name together? This is my command **awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV**

Comment: @FARAH what do you mean by column name together ?

Comment: @FARAH : if you remove `NR>1`, if your file `Text_01012020.CSV` contains header then you will get column name

Comment: for example I have 3 column name: Age, School and Class but if I do above command, the column name excluded @Akshay Hegde . I want include the column name inside my data

Comment: @FARAH: Its because of `NR>1` just remove `NR>1` from your command, and see the result

Comment: I cannot delete NR>1. Because I only get column name. I want column name and the data in my splitting file. @Akshay Hegde

Comment: @FARAH: You mean you want header for each file right ?

Comment: Not. I want column name for each column. @Akshay Hegde

Comment: @FARAH: I am sorry  I didn't get you, if you can provide sample input and expected o/p so much time can be saved, this retains field name of each column while splitting `awk -v DATE="$(date +'%Y%m%d')" 'NR==1{h=$0;next}{s=$1; gsub(/"/,"",s); f="Assignment_"s"_"DATE".csv"; if(p!=f){ print h>f; p=f } print >f}'  your_file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV
```

Just set "OFS" configuration, then output will be with comma.

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy I already get it but wait I also want column name inside my file. when i use this, the column name excluded.

Comment: awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR==1{FIRST_LINE=$0}NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); if(!a[$1]++){print FIRST_LINE > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv" } print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' Text_01012020.CSV         add column name with first line, and output it when you met the first "$1"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include your column name, then read it with the case when `NR==1`:

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS="," } NR==1 {COLUMN_NAME=$1} NR>1 { gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"COLUMN_NAME"_"DATE".csv"}' a.txt
```

And you can also learn for yourself with this  [great tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)